# Using Camel and Netty 4 with an unreachable Socket does not run into onException-part but returns the stacktrace

Tags: java, apache-camel, netty

I have a simple Camel route with a Netty 4 part as client to a socket. If the socket is not reachable, an java.net.ConnectException is thrown correctly but is not caught in the onException configured part but delivered as Exchange body. Is there any chance to catch this one?

- Camel 2.16.1
- Netty 4.0.33.Final

Routebuilder

```
public void configure() throws Exception {
    if (faultProcessor != null) {
        onException(Exception.class).handled(true).process(faultProcessor).stop();
    }

    from(from)
        .routeId(routeId)
        .process(preProcessor)
        .loadBalance()
            .failover(attempts, false, true, java.io.IOException.class)
            .to("netty4:tcp://server:port?clientMode=true&sync=true&allowDefaultCodec=false&clientInitializerFactory=#clientInitializerFactory&disconnect=true&usingExecutorService=false&workerGroup=#sharedPool")
        .end()
        .process(postProcessor)
        .to(to);
}
```

Stacktrace

```
java.net.ConnectException: Cannot connect to server:port
at org.apache.camel.component.netty4.NettyProducer.openChannel(NettyProducer.java:419)
at org.apache.camel.component.netty4.NettyProducer$NettyProducerPoolableObjectFactory.makeObject(NettyProducer.java:487)
at org.apache.camel.component.netty4.NettyProducer$NettyProducerPoolableObjectFactory.makeObject(NettyProducer.java:482)
at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1188)
at org.apache.camel.component.netty4.NettyProducer.process(NettyProducer.java:201)
at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:141)
at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190)
at org.apache.camel.processor.loadbalancer.FailOverLoadBalancer.processExchange(FailOverLoadBalancer.java:277)
at org.apache.camel.processor.loadbalancer.FailOverLoadBalancer.process(FailOverLoadBalancer.java:232)
at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190)
```

Comment: I think you configured the failover step to not inherit the error handler of the route. Is the error handler fired if you use `.failover(java.io.IOException.class)` instead?

Comment: Hi Ralf. This did the trick. It is essential to set the inheritErrorHandler to true. If you like, post your answer to win your laurels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You happen to configure the load balancer step to not inherit the error handler of the route. The error handler should fire if you use

```
.failover(java.io.IOException.class)
```

or

```
.failover(attempts, true, true, java.io.IOException.class)
```